# Load static CMS block with directives

Tags: magento-1.7, cms-block, template-directive

I created a block under **CMS -> Static Blocks** with the following content:

```
<a href="http://www.foo.com">
   <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/email/751-footer.png"}}"/>
</a>
```

---

Unfortunately the *media directive* interprets to `src="{{media url="` when I try to load the **CMS Block** via

```
$signaturemodel = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load('email_signature');

$signature = $signaturemodel->hasData() ? $signaturemodel->getContent() : "";
echo $signature;
```

Is there any chance to get the correct media url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different solutions depending on the context.

---

**e.g.**

```
// use thestatic block email_signature
$signature = '';
$block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')
    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->load('email_signature');

if ($block->getIsActive()) {
    /* @var $helper Mage_Cms_Helper_Data */
    $helper    = Mage::helper('cms');
    $processor = $helper->getBlockTemplateProcessor();
    $signature = $processor->filter($block->getContent());
}

echo $signature;
```

---

**or in a .phtml-File**

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')
     ->setBlockId('email_signature')
     ->toHtml();
```

For better understanding have a look at `app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Block.php`